# Active Directory(AD) Authentication in Azure Sql not working

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get Azure AD Authentication working against my Azure SQL Database.

- I created a PaaS database and it's associated PaaS Sql Server.
- I assigned MY Azure AD account as "Active Directory admin" of the "PaaS Sql Server".

*Next, I logged in to SSMS using MY domain account to create the user:*

```
CREATE USER [xxx@yyy.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER; 
GO
sp_addrolemember db_datareader,  [xxx@yyy.com];  
GO
sp_addrolemember
db_datawriter,  [xxx@yyy.com];  
GO
```

*When I attempt to login with the xxxxx@yyy.com account , I get back:*

```
   Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

    Server Name: zzzzz.database.windows.net
    Error Number: 18456
    Severity: 14
    State: 1
    Line Number: 65536
```

What am I missing ?

Weird observation, if I intentionally use the wrong password I get back this error:
*AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50126: Invalid username or password*, that tells the AD is somehow working, but something is broken in the overall process.

Another weird observation:
If I add a valid AD account, it succeeds

```
CREATE USER [xxx@yyy.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

If I generate a bad AD account

```
CREATE USER [xxxABC@yyy.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

I get back:

```
Principal 'xxxABC@yyy.com' could not be found or this principal type is not supported.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a "simialr post"

**The Anonymous Logon error occurs when you haven't specified the database you want to connect to.** Simply select "options" on the SSMS login screen and type in the database name you want to connect to. This is because your user is a contained user on the database it was created in. It does not exist on Master. – Greg Grater Mar 7 '17 at 1:23

This fixed my issue -- hours wasted!!!

Note: for ODBC conenctions the user must also be created in master

Comment: uuuhh this saved me quite some time!, indeed this fixed my issue as well. MS should improve its error message!